# Reading values from file Geodatabase table and assigning those values to variable

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, file-geodatabase, zonal-statistics

I created a table using the zonal statistics as a table tool which contains some percentile values of a raster (90%, 75%, etc). The table is 1 row and contains the percentile values. I want to take each percentile value and assign it to a variable (PER_90, PER_75, ...).

How do you use ArcPy to read in the table and assign values to these variables?

Comment: For the record if you wanted to achieve the same in modelbuilder you would use the model only tool [Get Field Value](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/get-field-value.htm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`da.SearchCursor()`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm):

```py
import arcpy

zonetable = r'C:\folder\data.gdb\zonstats' #Change
fieldnames = ['field90', 'field75','field50'] #Change

PER_90, PER_75, PER_50 = [row for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(zonetable, fieldnames)][0]
```